# How to customize "LinkItemNotFoundUrl" code?

Tags: sitecore-client

We have a website running on `Sitecore 10.2` and having multiple countries.

So in each country, if the particular link not found in rich text field, we need to redirect to particular country home page instead of `/sitecore/service/notfound.aspx`.

Comment: Are you using Sitecore SXA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a processor to the `renderField` pipeline to perform a replacement of the default value of the setting with the value that applies to the context site.

Sitecore resolves the internal links in the Rich Text Editor by using the `ExpandLinks` processor in the `renderField` pipeline (located in the web.config file) converting the GUID into valid URLs, but letting the external links unhandled. So if you want to manipulate links, you could do it by adding a new processor into the renderField pipeline.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField;
 
namespace MySitecoreExtensions.Pipelines.RenderField
{
    public class AddTargetAttributes
    {
        public void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
        {
            if (args.FieldTypeKey == "rich text")
            {
                // custom logic to replace default value.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Patch config

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
            <renderField>
                <processor type="MySitecoreExtensions.Pipelines.RenderField.AddTargetAttributes, MySitecoreExtensions" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetInternalLinkFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
            </renderField>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

References:
https://kirkegaard-at.blogspot.com/2015/10/sitecore-get-external-links-rte.html?m=0

https://sitecoretechfire.wordpress.com/2018/05/12/replace-external-links-and-internal-links-in-rich-text-field-dynamically/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @sumit. I will check.

Comment: It is somewhat overwriting the default URL construction. So we need to add the apply the logic for Media URLs as it is not rendering with friendly URL. 

     if (hrefValue.Contains("-/media") || hrefValue.Contains("~/media"))
     {
      fieldValue = fieldValue.Replace(hrefValue, hrefValue);

Answer (score 2):

For this, you can use the following approach. Create a custom processor and inherit it using `HttpRequestProcessor`. And get your item on the basis of some logic and then redirect the user to that page. This is how it will implement.

Create a class that will hold the logic.

```
public class ErrorNotFoundProcessor : Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestArgs args)
        {
            if (Sitecore.Context.Item == null && Sitecore.Context.Database != null)
            {
                // Write your own logic to get the item using the args. args will contain the request context arguments
                var errorNotFoundItem = < write your logic to get item >;
                if (errorNotFoundItem != null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                    Sitecore.Context.Item = errorNotFoundItem;
                }
            }
            return;
        }
    }
```

And finally path it like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
      <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
          <httpRequestBegin>
            <processor type="Yourassembly.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ErrorNotFoundProcessor, Yourassembly.Pipelines"
                patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
          </httpRequestBegin>
        </pipelines>
      </sitecore>
    </configuration>
```

Ref: https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/enable-smart-and-safe-error-pages-in-sitecore

Updates: As per the comments, you can do it by extending the `itemurlbuilder`. Refer to this article to implement it.

https://edwenkerk.hashnode.dev/multi-custom-links-with-sitecore-10-using-itemurlbuilder

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks @Sumit. But It would need to implement in the place of rendering rich text field content. 

Because all the internal link fields are resolved with the notfound.aspx page(LinkItemNotFoundUrl settings).

Comment: @Astle You can refer to this link. https://sitecorecommerce.wordpress.com/2015/10/19/sitecore-404-easy-and-seo-friendly/

Comment: You can do it by also extending the `ExecuteRequest` and patch it

Comment: I need to implement the changes on link resolver of rich text paragraph content. It is using the LinkItemNotFoundUrl settings.

Comment: @Astle I think what you are looking for is to customize the Item URL build. So this article will help you to implement https://edwenkerk.hashnode.dev/multi-custom-links-with-sitecore-10-using-itemurlbuilder

Comment: Thanks @sumit. I will check.